# Make Hook in main-menu

Tags: routes

I created a module containing the following files:

- menu_imoveis.info
- menu_imoveis.module

The content of menu_imoveis.info is the following.

```
    name = Menu Imoveis
    description = Adiciona imoveis ao menu.
    package = Imoveis
    core = 7.x
    version = 7.x-dev

    files[] = menu_imoveis.module
```

**The content of menu_imoveis.module is the following.

```
function menu_imoveis_menu() {
  $items['node/27'] = array(
    'title' => 'Example Page',
    'menu_name' => 'main-menu',
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
  );

  return $items;
}
```

The code I wrote doesn't work.

Comment: Did you clear your cache "Admin -> Config -> Performance -> clear cache". Or `drush cc all`. When you use hook_menu() you should clear your cache to see the changes. Also, I get you speak 2 languages -- I recommend trying to write your code in 1 language (english) so it's more maintainable.

Comment: Tanks tenken, But I clear the cache and run cron.

Comment: Where is the page callback?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish. I suggest menu_example for learning how Menu API works: http://api.drupal.org/api/examples/menu_example%21menu_example.module/7

Answer (score 1):

Taken from [this comment](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7#comment-28983), written by [zifiniti](http://api.drupal.org/user/313533):

> I was having trouble getting a menu item to display with the following code:
>
> ```
> function mymodule_menu() {
>   $items['custom-page'] = array(
>     'title' => 'Custom Page',
>     'menu_name' => 'main-menu',
>     'access arguments' => array('access custom pages')
>   );
>
>   return $items;
> }
> ```
>
> It was continuously denying me access to the specified path in addition to not displaying the item in the menu. I discovered that the reason behind this is if you do not specify a page callback, then the access callback will acquire a value of 0 in the database and thus render that path/menu item inaccessible.
>
> Working code:
>
> ```
> function mymodule_menu() {
>   $items['custom-page'] = array(
>     'title' => 'Custom Page',
>     'menu_name' => 'main-menu',
>     'page callback' => 'mymodule_custom_page',
>     'access arguments' => array('access custom pages')
>   );
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Ok Looking at it you are trying to edit a menu item which is already created. So you need to use the [HOOK_menu_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7) function.

```
function  mymodule_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items['node/27']['title'] = 'Something';
}
```

Also you might need to clear cache for this function to be triggered.

Comment: Actually, node/27 is not defined; it is node/%node that is defined.

Comment: Yes that is correct. My mistake.